# Your query does not include the specified expression "ID" as part of aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MSAccess I have the query below. When I try to run the query gives the error `Your query does not include the specified expression "ID" as part of aggregate function` and I can't find the reason. What is the problem in my query?

```
SELECT
   Count(t2.subjectid) AS CountOfsubjectid,
   t2.pname,
   (
      select
         max(outcometime) 
      from
         table1 t1 
      where
         t1.id = t2.id 
   )
   AS showntime 
FROM
   table2 AS t2 
WHERE
   t2.outcome = "accepted" 
GROUP BY
   t2.pname,
   t2.showntime;
```

**UPDATE (SAMPLE DATA):**

**Table1:**

```
ID  outcometime pname  outcome  subjectid
1   20181111    USB    shown    Ux1ku
1   20181113    USB    shown    Ux1ku
2   20181115    USB    shown    Tsn2f
3   20181116    USB    shown    O93nf
2   20181114    USB    shown    Tsn2f
2   20181112    USB    shown    Tsn2f
```

**Table2:**

```
ID  outcometime pname       outcome     subjectid
1   20181118    USB         accepted    Ux1ku
2   20181119    USB         accepted    Tsn2f
3   20181117    USB         accepted    O93nf
```

**Desired Result:**

```
pname     showntime     countofsubjectid
USB       20181113         1
USB       20181115         1
USB       20181116         1
```

Also updated the sample data. It was wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also add the desire result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are attempting to run a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause encapsulated in an aggregate query and then reference this very subquery by alias in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Consider using a derived table to first run your unit level with subquery and then in outer main query run your aggregation.

```
SELECT 
    dt.pname,
    COUNT(subjectid) AS CountOfsubjectid,
    dt.showntime
FROM 
  (SELECT
         t2.subjectid
         t2.pname,
         (
            select
               max(outcometime) 
            from
               table1 t1 
            where
               t1.id = t2.id 
         )
         AS showntime 
   FROM
        table2 AS t2 
   WHERE
        t2.outcome = 'accepted'
  ) AS dt
GROUP BY
   dt.pname,
   dt.showntime;
```

However, consider avoiding the inefficient correlated subquery to run for every row in table to joining on an aggregate query for the `MAX` calculated **once** and then run aggregation again for `COUNT` on main level.

```
SELECT
   t2.pname,
   COUNT(t.subjectid) AS CountOfsubjectid,
   agg.showntime 
FROM
   table2 AS t2 
INNER JOIN 
    (
     select 
        t1.id,
        max(outcometime) as showntime
     from
        table1 t1 
     group by 
        t1.id                     
     ) AS agg
  ON t2.id = agg.id
WHERE
   t2.outcome = 'accepted'    
GROUP BY
   t2.pname,
   agg.showntime;
```

Comment: I think `COUNT(t.subjectid)` should be `COUNT(t2.subjectid)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to write this as:

```
SELECT Count(t2.subjectid) AS CountOfsubjectid,
       t2.name,
       (select max(outcometime) 
        from table1 as t1 inner join
             table2 as tt2
             on t1.id = tt2.id
        where tt2.name = t2.name
      ) as showntime 
FROM table2 AS t2 
WHERE t2.outcome = "accepted" 
GROUP BY t2.name;
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't give the expected result